# set locale so no translation occurs

Tags: c, mfc, locale

I have some legacy MFC code that doesn't use unicode and in some places reads text from files using fopen / fgets.  For non-ASCII characters this makes a translation to what I assume is MBCS in the current locale.  For example if I have the line character Ø in my input file it gets translated to two characters.  If I compile a small test console program, this translation does not happen.  Is there an easy way in MFC to disable this translation?  Longer term the code is due for a rewrite, so really looking for a quick short term patch until this takes place.  Currently thinking of writing an alternative fgets based on fread.

**Edit:** Input file is encoded as ANSI, hex dump of test case below.  If I copy and paste the text below directly into my application it works fine, the translation is happening on fgets in the application.

[image: Hex dump of test case]

If I write a small test application, as shown below, the translation doesn't happen

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    char input[1024];

    FILE *f = fopen("c:\\temp\\myfile.txt", "rt");
    fgets(input, 1023, f);
    fclose(f);
    puts(input);
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit2**  GetSystemDefaultLocaleName and GetUserDefaultLocaleName return EN-ie in both the working test application and the application that is carrying out a translation.  Both projects have Character set = Not Set in the general program configuration (was previously MBCS which I'd thought was the problem).

Comment: What is the System Locale on you machine? (Languge?) What Encoding is the input file? (Incidentally [Ø](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ø) is two bytes in UTF-8.) Which Visual Studio Version?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015, question edited to cover other details

Comment: Is your system locale English? What do `getlocale` and its Win32 variants produce in the faulty application?

Comment: *"ANSI"* is meaningless, unless you also specify the code page that it is being used with. If you know the code page used by the text file, you can (temporarily) set the thread's locale to the one matching the text file. Use [SetThreadLocale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnls/nf-winnls-setthreadlocale), or [setlocale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setlocale-wsetlocale) and [_configthreadlocale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/configthreadlocale) for use with the CRT.

Comment: I don't see anything in the reference regarding a character set translation for `fgets()`. According to the reference of [`fopen()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx) for mode "t", such translation should only happen when using Unicode IO functions like `fgetws()`. What is the actual content of the `input` variable after the `fgets()` call of the MFC program as shown by the debugger (in hex form)?

Comment: After you changed the character set in the preferences did you do a full recompile?

Comment: Yes, full clean and rebuild all, guessing its an include file somewhere in my stdafx.h on the project that's showing the problem, but easier to rewrite than track down at this point.

Comment: Maybe writing a small console application to test this code fragment doesn't reproduce the error. A better testing scenario would be to convert this code to a Windows application instead (`WinMain()` instead of `main()`), or better yet create a new MFC application and put the code there. I suspect that the problem occurs because you have English as default language, but the Ø character is not defined for English (although it does exist in the Western-1252 codepage). A very common error with English Windows machines and non-English data or vice-versa.